# How to create an empty dataframe with specified columns AND number of rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I want to be able to rbind together. They have the similar information in them, but not in the same order and not with the same column names (and this is a mix of strings, integers, and real numbers, so matrices will not work).

What I then need to do is convert one of the dataframes (we'll call it new_df) into the same structure as the other dataframe (we'll call it `old_df`).

I want to create an empty dataframe with the column structure of `old_df` AND the same number of rows as `new_df`.

I know I can create the first part of that with `empty_df <- old_df[0,]`, but how can I specify the number of rows?

I know the number of rows I want to end up with, so I'd like to specify that. I cannot find this anywhere.

What I want is something like this (if this worked):

`empty_df <- old_df[rep(0,nrow(new_df)),]`

I tried:

`empty_df <- old_df[rep(0,nrow(new_df)),]`

- This just does the same as `old_df[0,]` with 0 rows

`empty_df <- old_df[0,]`

`empty_df$ID <- new_df$ids`

- Obviously that doesn't work as I am trying to add a different number of rows

Comment: something like this? `as.data.frame(matrix(,nrow(df),ncol(df)))`

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask help on your *y* solution of empty data frame but not the *x* problem of *why* you need such an object. My guess is you will then iterate through loops to assign rows and cols whereas vectorized methods may be available.

Comment: @Wimpel Unfortunately, I cannot use matrices to initialize because I need to preserve the various classes of the "old_df" dataframe.

Comment: @Parfait I am *trying* to initialize the number of rows for the exact reason that I don't want to loop through anything. I've stated the "why" in the question (I need to rbind these two dataframes).

Comment: I'm confused. Then why do you need an *empty* data frame? Please show us a sample of both data frames.

Comment: To summarize: You want to bind two dataframes `old_df` and `new_df` that have similar data but different column names and different column order. To that end you want to create a third dataframe `empty_df` with the structure of `old_df` and the same number of rows as `new_df`. We don't know what exactly what's supposed to happen next, but since your goal is to combine `old_df` and `new_df` we can conjecture that you want to populate `empty_df` with the data from `new_df`, and then bind `old_df` and `empty_df`. Is this correct? And if so, why not just rename and reorder `new_df`'s columns?

Comment: @gersht that is correct. I have accepted an answer below, but to answer your question of why not rename and reorder, truth is that I could (and then filter out any columns that are not in old_df and fill in blank columns for ones that are in old_df and not in new_df), but I thought that might be the same amount of work as this approach (or perhaps a little more seeing as how there any many more columns in old_df than there are in new_df). I am also a little paranoid and wanted to make *sure* that the formatting is identical before combining them.

Comment: @jvel I think it's more work. You are creating an intermediate dataframe that has to be populated with data from `new_df`. This is basically just renaming the column in `new_df` via a more circuitous route. It would be far easier to just use something like `new_df %>% rename(x = a, y = b) %>% bind_rows(old_df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following hack will do what the OP wants. It creates the number of rows by setting the `row.names` attribute directly. And if a dataframe has row names, it must have the corresponding rows.

```
empty_df <- old_df[0, ]
attr(empty_df, 'row.names') <- 1:nrow(new_df)

str(empty_df)
#'data.frame':  300 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num 
# $ Sepal.Width : num 
# $ Petal.Length: num 
# $ Petal.Width : num 
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..:
```

The dataframe `empty_df` now has 300 rows.

**Data creation code.**

The test data creation code uses the built-in dataset `iris`.

```
set.seed(1234)

old_df <- iris
new_df <- rbind(iris, iris)
new_df <- new_df[, sample(ncol(new_df))]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That is exactly what I need.